# Java: If abstract class Foo returns Object, can concrete class Bar return String or Integer?

Tags: java, generics, casting, abstract-class

I have a Java enum with an abstract class, like this:

```
public enum Strategy {
    STRING {
        @Override
        public String execute() {
            return "ABCDE";
        }
    },
    INTEGER {
        @Override
        public Integer execute() {
            return 12345;
        }
    };
    public abstract Object execute();
}
```

When I use it, I expect to be able to do this:

```
String text = Strategy.STRING.execute();
Integer num = Strategy.INTEGER.execute();
```

However, my IDE warns me that these are incompatible types and won't compile. To resolve it, I have to instead do this:

```
String text = (String) Strategy.STRING.execute();
Integer num = (Integer) Strategy.INTEGER.execute();
```

I'd rather not have to cast the results of my `execute()` methods. Is there any way to return the type specified in the concrete method signature, rather than returning `Object`?

Comment: What's wrong with casting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you override a method, the subclass method can be declared to return a refinement of the superclass return type. However, code that calls the superclass method has no way of knowing what the actual type is of the returned object. In your case, all it knows is that it's an `Object` of some sort. That's why you have to cast it before assigning to a more specific variable.

Enum objects are a little weird. When you compile this code:

```
Strategy.STRING.execute();
```

the compiler generates this bytecode (output from `javap -c`):

```
getstatic     #2 // Field Strategy.STRING:LStrategy;
invokevirtual #3 // Method Strategy.execute:()Ljava/lang/Object;
```

As you can see, it treats `Strategy.STRING` as a static field of class `Strategy`, and that field is of type `Strategy`. Thus, despite appearances, the calling code doesn't know that it's calling the `STRING` version of `execute()`.

I wonder, though, why you would want to do all this. Designing an API that requires a cast seems contrary to the spirit of object-oriented programming.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my case, I need several enums that will return Strings and several that will return Integers...and based on the names, it will be clear which is which. But I suppose you're right. I should use two enums, one for String returns and one for Integer returns, if I'm going to do such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Your enum constants are compiled to `static` fields. Something like

```
public static final Strategy INTEGER = new Strategy() {
    @Override
    public Integer execute() {
        return 12345;
    }
};
```

Because they are simply `Strategy` references, you only have access to the `Strategy` 'interface' which declares the `execute()` method as returning an `Object`.

So, no, you won't be able to get it to do

```
Integer num = Strategy.INTEGER.execute();
```

in this way.

Comment: The real question is: why would you want to get it to do something like that anyway?

Comment: @arshajii Indeed. Shaun?

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my case, I need several enums that will return Strings and several that will return Integers...and based on the names, it will be clear which is which. But I suppose you're right. I should use two enums, one for String returns and one for Integer returns, if I'm going to do such a thing.